# how to select nested/embedded document in mongodb and php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have collected document like this

```
{ _id:8123713291
   report: {
            name_of_report: "foo"
   }
}
```

And I tried to do this

```
.
.
.
.
cursor=collection->find($query)
foreach($cursor as $doc){
  foreach($doc['report'] as $docc){
    echo $docc['name_of_report'];
  }
}
```

But there is some error, the error say "Illegal string offset 'name_of_report'". What's wrong with that code ?

Comment: What is wrong with `echo $doc['report']['name_of_report'] ` or even `$report = $doc['report']; echo $report['name_of_report']` ? Works for me. Otherwise you would be iterating other the keys of the innner object, and I cannot see why you would want to do that.

Comment: Thank you for replied the answer. Both of echo that you said are working! Omg it's like magic sir! :) Why did you answer in comment ? I cannot give you a check, for your answer on my question instead. @NeilLunn

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit. It should work now:-

```
$cursor=collection->find($query);
$cursor=iterator_to_array($cursor);
foreach($cursor as $doc){
  foreach($doc as $docc){
    echo $docc['name_of_report'];
  }
}
```